# prime function in a for loop using Math operations

Tags: primes

guys

I saw a function(the function is just below) that check wether a number is prime and return a value but I don't understand the operations made in the code. Can someone explain me mathematically? Also is there better algorithms for prime checker function?

bool IS_prime(int number) 
{

```
for (long long j = 2; j*j <= number; j++)
{
    if (number == 2)
        return true;
    if (number == 3)
        return true;
    if (number % j == 0)
        break;
    else if (j + 1 > sqrt(number))
        return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Questions must involve real code that you own or maintain. Pseudocode, hypothetical code, or stub code should be replaced by a concrete implementation. Questions seeking an explanation of someone else's code are also off-topic. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

## **What it's doing**

Basically, this is just going through all the numbers up to the square root of `number`, and seeing if they divide evenly. They divide evenly if `number % j == 0`. If anything divides evenly, then the number is not prime and the function should return `false`. However, there is no `return false` anywhere in the program, and it actually relies on undefined behavior.

Try going through it yourself with `number` equal to 9. The loop will go until `j == 3`, and then it will terminate because of the `break` statement. After that, the function doesn't know what to return since there isn't any `return` statement outside of the loop. On my computer it defaults to `false`, but if you compile with `gcc -Wall` you'll get this:

```
review.c: In function ‘is_prime’:
review.c:18:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

This can be rectified by replacing the `break` statement with `return false`, and putting a `return true` on the outside of the loop. It should be `true` at the end because at that point the function has gone through all the possible factors and found none that divide evenly.

## Improvements

1. `j` is never going to be larger than `number` due to the constraints in the loop, so `j` should also be of type `int`. (Or `number` should be of type `long long`)
2. The two `if` statements at the beginning of the loop that check if `number` is `2` or `3` are going to be the same every time, but are evaluated at the beginning of every loop for no good reason. Put them before the loop.
3. The middle statement of the loop, `j*j <= number` and the `else if` at the end, `if j + 1 > sqrt(number)` are doing the same job, which is limiting the amount of times the loop repeats. Replace `j*j <= number` with `j + 1 <= sqrt(number)` and get rid of the `else if` at the end.
4. I don't know what `sqrt` function you're using, but I'm guessing it's from `math.h`. That function takes a `double`, so either use a square root function that takes an `int` or replace `j + 1 <= sqrt(number)` with `j*j <= number`. Mathematically, it's pretty much the same thing (though we can get rid of the unnecessary `+1`), but we avoid using that function incorrectly.
5. This loop will check every number up to the square root, but if `number` has any even primes then it is a multiple of two. You check early on if `number` is even, and then only check odd numbers in the loop. That will cut out half of the iterations with one quick `if` statement in the beginning.

## **All together**

I replaced `j` with `i` because of style. Use `j` if you prefer, it doesn't matter.

```
bool is_prime(int number)
{
    //By definition a prime has to be greater than 1
    if(number < 2)
        return false;

    //Check this before the next if statement so that is_prime(2) doesn't return false
    if(number == 2)
        return true;

    //See if number is even
    if(number % 2 == 0)
        return false;

    //Increasing by two each time so that only odds are checked
    for(int i = 3; i * i <= number; i += 2)
    {
        if(number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    //If the loop doens't find anything, then it is prime 
    return true;
}
```

## **Testing**

```
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("is %2d prime? %s\n", i, is_prime(i) ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Will print out:

```
is  0 prime? no
is  1 prime? no
is  2 prime? yes
is  3 prime? yes
is  4 prime? no
is  5 prime? yes
is  6 prime? no
is  7 prime? yes
is  8 prime? no
is  9 prime? no
is 10 prime? no
is 11 prime? yes
is 12 prime? no
is 13 prime? yes
is 14 prime? no
is 15 prime? no
is 16 prime? no
is 17 prime? yes
is 18 prime? no
is 19 prime? yes
```

Everything looks right from this, so we can call it a day. Note that if generating a list of primes like this is what this function is used for, you should consider using a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) instead.